# External Seagate HDD is causing an error when copying files over to my laptop

Tags: boot, 18.04, hard-drive, external-hdd

I did a clean install of Ubuntu 18 LTS and updated and upgraded. I have some files on an external HDD that I use as my backup HDD and I tried copying it on my laptop. I copied those files on my laptop and when I restarted my laptop I have been prompted with the following error.

[HDD Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgiiB.jpg)

The laptop is brand new, Asus Vivo book so I am sure it is not a hardware issue (also I've had this problem on my previous laptop which I changed because of this issue because some people told me that the HDD is messed up). I reinstalled ubuntu again, updated, upgraded all went fine. Restarted it a couple of times, fine, used it for a while, fine, copied the files from my external HDD stopped working with the same error. I am pretty sure it is the external HDD. Now the issue is ... I do need those files from the external HDD. Any suggestions?

UPDATE1: I can access and use the files well from the external HDD

Comment: What files are you trying to copy from the external drive, and what is the destination of the files?

Comment: just random files. Like photos, music, pdfs, ebooks. It's just whatever I had on my HDD from the past 4 years. Destination? the hdd of my new laptop. the path is the new ex4 partition.

Comment: What commands are you using to copy back to your HDD?

Comment: Sudo cp -rv [from] [to]

Comment: This may be irrelevant, but when you use `sudo` to make the copies, `root` becomes the owner of the files.  This may cause some issues...

Comment: For example, I use `rsync` to make backups, with the command `sudo ionice -c 3 rsync --progress --delete --no-compress --exclude={.cache,.dbus} -avhH /home/chick/ /media/chick/Lbck/backup` - this backs up to an external drive, excludes the config and dbus directories, and preserves owner and group designators.

Comment: Without an example of the EXACT cp command(s) that you use, it'll be harder to determine where the problem is. What files are you trying to copy? Do you know how to `fsck` your Ubuntu partition to correct the current problem? Report back to @heynnema

Comment: If you had used `-rvp`  (recursive, verbose, preserve-ownership-timestamps) you'd have been better. I don't see an error, only that something is probably missing, but without more information we can only guess; did you overwrite something in /etc ?, /boot ? or you have two devices with same UUID in the machine (if you cloned a drive for example). I would login to emergency mode & look at /etc/fstab & then your /boot/grub/ looking for inconsistencies.